# ActiveRecord-like updates in Meteor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meteor

In Rails, thanks to the incredible ActiveRecord library, we can do things like this:

```
bear = Bear.find(id)
bear.eyes = 'blue'
bear.friends += 1
bear.save
```

And the changes are then saved into the database.

In Meteor I can do this:

```
bear = Bears.findOne({});
bear.eyes = 'blue';
bear.friends++;
```

The two changes made are only made to the local copy in memory. As far as I can see the changes cannot be persisted without calling a Mongo update statement.

```
Bears.update({
    _id: bear._id,
    $inc: { friend: 1 },
    eyes: 'blue'
});
```

I love Meteor, it is pretty amazing... but this would seem to be a big step backwards if it cannot be done.

Is there some way to persist **bear** as we used to do in Rails / ActiveRecord?

Comment: Meteor does not seem to have a model layer at all, but rather just deals with MongoDB collections directly as you have noticed. It might be possible to use another ORM system with meteor, but I have never tried. There are several ORMs available for node.js some based on Rails ActiveRecord (and some on the original Martin Fowler Active Record concept).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this writing, meteor does not include an ORM in its core packages. There is, however, a community package called [astronomy](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy) which implements ActiveRecord-style models. The complete documentation can be found [here](http://astronomy.jagi.io/).

Recommended reading:

- To create a simple model layer using the tools that the core packages provide, have a look at [this article](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models).
- To read a summary of where the community is heading, check out [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/guide/issues/10) on the official [guide repo](https://github.com/meteor/guide).

Comment: Astronomy looks really great ... reminds a bit of Restangular from the Angular world. The philosophy of "Just make the programmer's life easier" works for me.